# Active Directory: If Global Catalog has only benefits, why would someone decide to not install it?

Tags: active-directory, domain

I’m studying Active Directory and I'm following a video training by Total Seminars called “Active Directory with Windows Server 2016” that I find, so far, very good.

Talking about Global Catalog (Chap. 1 – Par. 10), the instructor says that this “role” is very important and, as good practice, it is better to put it on every domain controller, independently if we have just one simple domain or a complex structure with more domains since, she says, GC does not cause any disk space increment, neither any negative impact on performances nor on replication.

So I wonder: if global catalog is so important and if it has only benefits without any sort of downside why it is not simply installed r?

Why would someone decide to not install it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in multi domain forest you should not put Global Catalog on domain controllers that have Infrastructure Master FSMO role. The infrastructure master is responsible for updating cross-domain object references each domain controller in the domain. When distinguished name of a active directory object is changed and that object is a a member of group in the other domain, the group might temporarily appear not to contain that member. The infrastructure master of the group's domain is responsible for updating the group so it knows the new distinguished name of the member. If the infrastructure master is be placed on a global catalog server, whenever it needs update it will try to find global catalog but in this case both are on same server so infrastructure master will believe that it has all updated information. So infrastructure master is not able to determine which cross-domain references have changed and won’t replicate to any other domain controller in domain.

That is the main reason why global catalog installation is optional.